# jQuery Innerfade Responsive Height

Tags: jquery, html

Im using jQuery Innerfade to create a slideshow. The slideshow is in a responsive div, so the width of the slideshow image also changes based on your device's resolution.

```
$('#services_slideshow').innerfade({
    animationtype: 'fade',
    speed: 750,
    timeout: 6000,
    type: 'sequence',
    containerheight: '228px'
});

<div id="services_slideshow">
    <img src="images/ss_6.jpg">
    <img src="images/services_four.jpg">
</div>
<p>
This is the text that follows the slideshow
</p>
```

The containerheight above looks fine on a desktop, but when you view on an iPad, the slideshow image width is now smaller, but the containerheight remains at 228px, causing a huge gap between the slideshow images and text.

I attempted to set the containerheight to "auto" but that did not work.

How can I set the containerheight to adjust when the resolution changes?

Comment: could you perhaps provide a jsfiddle that shows the problem?